# Why is print_r($_COOKIE) not showing all cookies stored?

Tags: php, cookies, printing

I'm posting today because i'm encountering something weird and didn't find an explanation to that behavior (even after searching on that forum and in the php documentation).

I have a **test.php** file in **/Desktop/PHP** that contains this code :

```
<?php
    setcookie('first_name', 'David', time() + 7*86400, null, null, false, true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Testing page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            Hey ! I remember you !<br />
            Your name is <?php echo $_COOKIE['first_name'] !
        </p>

        <p>
            echo '$_COOKIE ';
            print_r($_COOKIE);
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open that page in my browser with MAMP (so the link is **localhost:8888/test.php**) here's what I got :

> Hey ! I remember you !
>   Your name is David !
>
> $COOKIE Array
>   (
>       [first_name] => David
>   )

At first view it seems normal, but, what I don't understand is why print_r($_COOKIE) doesn't show all the cookies stored on my browser ? Is that related to the fact that I'm on a localhost page, and print_r($COOKIE) just show the cookie of the current domain ?

Thanks in advance for answers !

Comment: Your browser only send the cookie for the domain he's requesting. Why should he send cookies for any other domain? Thus you only get teh cookie that belongs to your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is only going to give you the cookies that are being passed through to your script. They are only the cookies that belong to the same domain. It would be a major security flaw if it sent all your cookies to every site.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to be obvious but I wasn't sure that was the reason why !
After all, even there would have been security issues; when we are working locally and trying to print the content of $_COOKIE we could have expected it to contain all the cookies stored in the browser.

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: No, I've no experience in Javascript, I've just finished learning HTML5 / CSS3 and I'm actually learning PHP / SQL and how to use the Symfony framework with it.

What would jQuery do ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the list of set cookies in your browser and check there are the fields Name, Content, Host, Path, Send for, Expires.
Your code line `setcookie('first_name', 'David', time() + 7*86400, null, null, false, true);` have Name='first_name',Content='David', expires='7*86400 seconds from now', Path='no path (in machine)', Host='no host', Send for='any http (if your browser respect the true entry, I don\'t understand surely this part)'.

When I set some cookie I replace those `null` for `ROOT_PATH` and `DOMAIN_NAME`, and I define these constant as `define('ROOT_PATH',__DIR__);` and `define('DOMAIN_NAME', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` in a configuration php file which I always create in my projects, where I set all constants and these stuff.

So, `print_r($_COOKIE);` will show you the cookies what are placed in the host you're running the test.php file.